# Where is the submitted $_POST array stored after an option page submission?

Tags: options, add-menu-page

What happens, when I click `Save Changes` on a option page, which was created by `add_menu_page()`? Where is the submitted data stored *before* the database transmission?

A `print_r($_REQUEST)` returns only the two `$_GET` parameters `page` and `settings-updated`.

I've checked the manual for `add_settings_field` and there is only the following hint:

> ... the saving will be done behind the scenes.

### Background

I'd like to optimize my process of creating a plugin settings page. I've already jumped on the [WP Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) with `add_settings_section` and `add_settings_field` long time ago, but it feels a bit uncomfortable to create a new callback function every time. So instead of creating the specific field/section code inside a callback, I'd like to create the complete settings page with `Zend_View`. All input fields would be created with `Zend_Form` and also attached to the view. In the end, the callback of `add_menu_page()` will return the rendered View-Object instead of the normal HTML output.

The HTML is stored inside a View-Template, located in `views/pages/admin/` (e.g. `default.phtml`).

The basic principle is already working I'm very happy with the result. Due to the use of `Zend_View`, I've to do the saving on my own. But WordPress seems to delete the submitted $_POST array. If I debug the output after a successfull form submission, only the two `$_GET` params above are set.

I've also attached the output of the function `settings_fields()` to the view, which generates the required hidden fields (`option_page`, `action`, `_wp_nonce`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found my fault.

The "problem" with `Zend_View` and `Zend_Form` is, that you have to check and save the submitted settings by yourself. But if you register a sanitize hook with `register_setting()`, WordPress will indeed not return any `$_POST` array and will immediatly submit the data to the defined option in the database.

The solution was to remove the call to `register_setting()` completely. I've also removed the call to `settings_field()` and set the hidden fields manually in the `Zend_Form` object.

```
$form = new Zend_Form();
$form->setAction('options.php?page=' . $this->getMenuSlug())
     ->setMethod('post');

$wpnonce = $form->createElement('hidden', '_wp_nonce');
$wpnonce->setValue(wp_create_nonce($this->getMenuSlug()));
```

The method `$this->getMenuSlug()` will return the id of the current generate admin page used in `add_page_menu()`.

The last part was to do the form validation before echoing the `Zend_View` object. This is done in the `renderView()` method, which will be called as callback in `add_menu_page()`.

```
public function renderView() {
    try {
        if($_POST['submit']) {
            // Check wp nonce
            if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_wp_nonce'], $this->getMenuSlug())) {
                wp_die(__('Nonce incorrect!'));
            } else {
                if($this->_form->isValid($_POST)) {
                    echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>' . __('Settings saved.') . '</strong></p></div>';
                    foreach ($this->_form->getElements() as $element) {
                        if(in_array($element->getName(), $this->_skipElements)) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        Webeo_Option::getInstance()->setValue($element->getName(), $element->getValue());
                    }

                    Webeo_Option::getInstance()->commit();
                } else {
                    echo '<div id="message" class="error fade"><p><strong>' . __('Errors occured.') . '</strong></p></div>';
                }
            }
        }

        echo $this->_form->render($this->_view);
        //echo $this->_view->render($this->getViewTemplate());
    } catch (Zend_View_Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

The `Webeo_Option` is just an object storage and could be replaced with `update_option()`.

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend ditching Zend View, and implementing your WordPress settings in a way that is consistent with WordPress coding practices and standards. `register_setting()` exists for a reason.

Answer (score 4):

You only need *one* callback function, as defined in your call to `register_setting()` ([Codex ref.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting)):

```
register_setting( $option_group, $option_name, $sanitize_callback );
```

Thus, all options are contained in an array, in a single database entry, `$option_name`.

Then, the callback function is passed the `$input` variable that holds all of the form-submitted data, the function manipulates/sanitizes those data, and returns the sanitized output:

```
function mytheme_sanitize_callback( $input ) {
    // sanitization functions go here
    return $sanitized_output;
}
```

So: *one* database entry, as an array of options; and *one* sanitization callback for form-submitted user data.

For more help, you might reference [this tutorial](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/).

Comment: And it should be noted if you ever use the settings API, you should always be passing `register_setting` the callback parameter and validating your input, or at the least passing it the name of an existing function to sanitize the input.

Comment: @Chip Thanks for your long tutorial. Very informative. But unfortunately this was indeed my fault to include the hidden fields generated by `register_setting` to my `Zend_View` object.